# Submit Auto Renew Subscription Apple Developer

Tags: ios, console, subscription

I am completely stuck here. I am trying to submit a subscription on the apple developer console. I have two apps that I am doing this for. One says the subscription is "Ready to Submit", and the other says "Missing Metadata"

Both are similar and I have the same info filled out, so why does one still say missing metadata? I have the screenshot, etc filled out.

Why does the one that says "ready to submit" have the button to submit greyed out?

I have been on this for hours and searched google and found no help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the missing metadata. I just removed the screenshot and localization, then re-added. Seems to have solved that.